# function within a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I have written a plugin that allows a user to select table cells:

https://jsfiddle.net/leeprice/Neftr/

I have the main functionality complete, however, I have a problem. I need to  be able to able to pass the `selected` function as a plugin option. You'll see where I've commented in the fiddle.

**The problem is, the function is only supposed to execute when `mouseDown = 1`, but it executes on `mousemove`**

any help appreciated :)

Comment: Right, so what's the problem? `selected` shouldn't be in quotes btw.

Comment: @RichardD The problem is, the function is only supposed to execute when mouseDown = 1, but it executes on mousemove

Comment: You should probably have mentioned that in your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use initialization:

```
$('table').cellSelect({selected: function() { 
                                    alert('selected'); }
                              });
```

And call your handler:

```
// Needs to execute here
if (options.selected)
    options.selected();
}
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Neftr/6/

Comment: the problem is, the function is only supposed to execute on when mouseDown = 1, but it executes on mousemove

Comment: It's because you've added handler directly to `mousemove`: `}).mousemove(options.selected).click(function() {`. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Neftr/9/

Comment: And this one fires a little bit less events: http://jsfiddle.net/Neftr/11/. But you still need to debug it.

Comment: getting there :) but what if I want the function to something like this `$(this).text('selected')` so the text of the selected table cell will change. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just pass as a param `this` when you calling function, and you will be able to get element on which `onmousemove` event triggered.

Comment: Here, I've moved a little code and copied code of handler calling to the click event. Probably you need to refactor it but this here is the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Neftr/12/

Answer (score 0):

change you options to

```
selected: function() {

}
```

so when calling the plugin you can do

```
$('table').cellSelect({
    selected:function() {
        alert('b');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Neftr/8/)

Pertinent changes:

In the intialisation you pass the anonymous function:

```
$(function() {
    $('table').cellSelect({ selected: function() { alert("foo"); }});
});
```

Then when required, run the function assigned to the `options.selected` parameter:

```
if (mouseDown === 1) {
    if (shiftDown === 1) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        options.selected; // run passed anonymous function, or default specified one.
    }
}
```

Comment: but the problem is, the function is only supposed to execute on when `mouseDown` = 1, but it executes on mousemove

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:  https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Neftr/3/

Just use `options.selected`

Comment: the problem is, the function is only supposed to execute on when mouseDown = 1, but it executes on mousemove

Comment: yes, but it's also inside the `if(mouseDown === 1)` statement